# Other jquery functions NOT working after successful ajax function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors

**EDIT**

JQUERY-AJAX REQUEST CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".form").submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $(this);
    var div_add_comment = $(form).parent();
    var div_comments = $(div_add_comment).parent();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $(form).serialize(),
        url: "includes/comment.php",
        success: function(msg){
            $(div_comments).html(msg);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

JQUERY SHOW ALL - COLLAPSE COMMENTS CODE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.see_all').click(function(){
    var thisItem = $(this);
    thisItem.parent().find('#comment2').slideDown('fast');
    thisItem.parent().find('.collapse').css('display','inline-block');
    thisItem.css('display','none');
    return false;
}); 

$('.collapse').click(function(){
     var thisItem = $(this);
     thisItem.parent().find('#comment2').slideUp('fast');
     thisItem.css('display','none');
     thisItem.parent().find('.see_all').css('display','inline-block');
     return false;
})
})
</script>
```

JQUERY REMOVE DEFAULT VALUE TEXT UPON FOCUS - TEXTAREA

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var Input = $('textarea[name=comment]');
var default_value = Input.val();

$(Input).focus(function() {
    if($(this).val() == default_value)
    {
         $(this).val("");
    }
}).blur(function(){
    if($(this).val().length == 0)
    {
        $(this).val(default_value);
    }
});
})
</script>
```

Please let me know if you need anything else, I have the damndest of time copying code and formatting it in these posts.

**END EDIT**

I am having a weird little problem. I have created a jquery-ajax function to transfer data from a comments section of my page. The page has an instance of this form under each user post. So this page will have X amount of posts with X amount of comments for each posts, like a social network. My ajax request sends, recieves and displays the data perfectly BUT I have two other jquery functions called on elements inside that no longer work after the ajax function returns the html. All the other ones not acted upon by the ajax function STILL WORK. I have the checked and rechecked the response html from the ajax function and it is identical to the html of a standard post-comment instance.

Please let me know what you would like to see or if you have questions.

Thanks, your help is always appreciated!

Comment: Sounds like an event binding issue - post your code

Comment: ok AlienWebguy, give me a moment.

Comment: Share code snipets... I've had a similar issue in the past I fixed, but I can't tell if you're having the same problem with out seeing some code.

Comment: What are your headers saying?

Comment: OK guys, posts my jquery code above, once again the problem is after an ajax request is submitted the other two jquery functions for removing the default value of the textarea and show-collapse comments functionality no longer work, as they do on the other post-comment instances on the page.

Comment: Is this representative of the architecture of your app? Do you have these snippets living in separate script tags and doc ready statements? This might be a load order issue. Try grouping them together in one doc ready and tag, then isolate parts of your UI code to try and tease out what is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to bind the jQuery functions in such a way that the element doesn't have to exist.

```
$('ul').on('click', 'li', function(){ /* do something */ });
```

This will execute on LIs that have been added after the binding of the function.

In your case you would want to bind to the parent of the comments section and target the elements that have the click behavior.

```
$('.comments')
    .on('click', '.see_all', function(){...})
    .on('click', '.collapse', function(){...})
    .on('focus', 'textarea[name=comment]', function(){...})
    .on('blur', 'textarea[name=comment]', function(){...})
```

Comment: I have posted some code above, could you elaborate on your pertaining to my edit?

Comment: OK, I'll give this a go ArrayKnight, this makes sense, I'll let you know.

Comment: ArrayKnight, thanks I was able to get the result I needed with your help! I really appreciate man. Checking as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the $() from form.

You have this:

```
var form = $(this);
    var div_add_comment = $(form).parent();
    var div_comments = $(div_add_comment).parent();
```

It should be this:

```
var form = $(this),
    div_add_comment = form.parent(),
    div_comments = $(div_add_comment).parent();
```

Since you declared *var form = $(this);* you don't need to wrap form...how you have it now is the equivalent of *$((form))*

Not sure if this will fix your problem, but jQuery may be getting hung up on this since you are spawning children from $(this).

Comment: tried this, it still works as it did before, but still having the same issue.